# Is Xcode vulnerable due to log4j?

Tags: vulnerability, macos, known-vulnerabilities, log4shell, xcode

After the log4j vulnerability was announced, I scanned my Mac to see if any applications were using it.

`find / -name "*log4j*" 2>/dev/null`

Here's the output that indicates that Xcode has log4j bundled in:

> ./System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/xcsd/node_modules/nano/node_modules/follow/browser/log4js.js
> ./System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/share/OSGi-Bundles/org.apache.logging.log4j.core-2.11.2.jar
> ./System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/share/OSGi-Bundles/org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar
> ./System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/share/OSGi-Bundles/org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl-2.11.2.jar
> ./System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/share/OSGi-Bundles/org.apache.logging.log4j.api-2.11.2.jar
> ./System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/share/OSGi-Bundles/com.apple.transporter.log4j2-1.0.0.jar
> ./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/xcsd/node_modules/nano/node_modules/follow/browser/log4js.js
> ./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/share/OSGi-Bundles/org.apache.logging.log4j.core-2.11.2.jar
> ./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/share/OSGi-Bundles/org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar
> ./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/share/OSGi-Bundles/org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl-2.11.2.jar
> ./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/share/OSGi-Bundles/org.apache.logging.log4j.api-2.11.2.jar
> ./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/share/OSGi-Bundles/com.apple.transporter.log4j2-1.0.0.jar

This is the latest Xcode from the app store as of Dec 16 but the version of log4j seems to be 2.11, which is apparently a vulnerable version.

So my question is: is my Mac vulnerable and should I delete Xcode? I don't really use Xcode except it's needed for Homebrew.

Comment: Are you exposing Xcode to the Internet? If not, it seems like anyone who could exploit the vulnerability would already be on your local machine and so you'd have other things to worry about.

Comment: Apparently Xcode uses Java code for uploading things into AppStore. If you don't do such upload it is unlikely that you will be vulnerable. Since you only use it for Homebrew (which uses c compilation toolchain from Xcode AFAIK), it's unlikely Java is even run in that usage. You can check in your processes though when you run Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the iTMSTransporter it will check into the update server and update log4J to 2.16.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but I can imagine a scenario where someone poisons a popular source code repo with the log4j2 exploit string, understanding that said string will get logged with log4j2 via Xcode.

Xcode user downloads the source code, unknowingly executes the exploit, and....then it's less clear.

Assuming I can get a shell via poisoned code with the exploit (haven't played with it, but the nickname "log4shell" seems instructive), then I (some attacker) need to be able to *do* something with it. Perhaps this same poisoned code could enter keystrokes macro-style, or do something else with the acquired shell.

If the vulnerability can be executed through Xcode, I'd assume someone can code up the follow-on steps to make it useful.

Perhaps the greater question is: in a target-rich environment (like, nearly *every* enterprise web service online), is it worth someone's time to target Xcode this way. Probably more lucrative to place APTs in all these compromised enterprises.

Comment: Thanks. Aren't developer laptops target-rich environments too?

Comment: Sure, you could have just what an attacker wants. But my thinking was that when it's as easy to get access as entering specially-crafted text into a comment form, or possibly making a request for a non-existent resource with a specially-crafted name, that assembling a complex multi-step attack just for Xcode devs might be further down the priority list.

Comment: If Java is only used by Xcode for uploading stuff into AppStore, then you're not vulnerable unless you do such upload. And even then it's a question of what would get logged. Unlike with HTTP servers where stuff like User-Agent header is logged routinely, or some user input such as username can get logged - it is far less likely that Xcode will log some thirdparty input. But it's not completely impossible, I agree - thus it is better to get an update to log4j core JAR or manually delete JndiLookup class from it, before uploading stuff to AppStore.